# Insertar 3 dias mas a la fecha actual sumar sabado y domingo

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo esto en php mysql

```
$fechaactual = Date("Y-m-d");
tep_db_query(
      "UPDATE " 
    . TABLE_ENTREGAS 
    . " SET fecha_calidad = DATE_ADD('" 
    . tep_db_input($fechaactual) 
    . "', INTERVAL 3 DAY) WHERE numero_contrato = '" 
    . $contrato['numero_contrato'] 
    . "'"
);
```

y necesito que si es jueves sumar 1 día más a los 3 dias del intervalo programado
y si es viernes sumar 2 dias más a los 3 dias del intervalo programado set en `fecha_calidad`.

es decir si el jueves es día 08/03/2018 al hacer el update el día jueves la fecha_calidad debera ser 1 dia + 3 dias del intervalo = 4 dias en `fecha_calidad`

es decir si el viernes es día 09/03/2018 al hacer el update el día viernes la fecha_calidad debera ser 2 dias (sábado y domingo) + 3 dias del intervalo = 5 dias en `fecha_calidad`

como seria el query para que reconozca la suma de 4 dias si es Jueves
como seria el query para que reconozca la suma de 5 dias si es viernes

en conclusión, nunca debe realizar un `update` a `fecha_calidad` con fecha sábado o domingo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por que no utilizar DateTime  para saber el día de la semana y usar un condicional.

Ejemplo:

```
<?php
$fecha = new DateTime('now');
$diaSemana = $fecha->format('N');
$fechaactual = $fecha->format('Y-m-d');

if ($diaSemana == 4){ // Jueves
        tep_db_query("UPDATE " . TABLE_ENTREGAS . " SET fecha_calidad = DATE_ADD('" . tep_db_input($fechaactual) . "', INTERVAL 4 DAY) WHERE numero_contrato = '" . $contrato['numero_contrato'] . "'");
} elseif ($diaSemana == 5){ // Viernes
    // hacer lo que corresponda el Viernes
} else { 
    // hacer lo que corresponda el si no es ni Jueves ni Viernes
}
```